# Atom terminal plugin cannot find command

Tags: bash, atom-editor, opensuse, xterm

I was trying to set up *Atom* editor and wanted to run terminal inside it just like i was doing in *Kate*. So i installed *atom-xterm* package, and tried to run my python script in it.

As you probably already realized, it didn't work. The problem was because it could not find *python3.9* inside /usr/bin folder, where it used to be. If i open my normal terminal (*Konsole*) as a separate window and run `python3.9` command it will work fine.

I tried to make some research and ran command `find /usr/bin -name "python*"` in both terminals, and their output was slightly different.

What xterm from Atom printed:

```
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3-config
/usr/bin/python3.8
/usr/bin/python3.8-config
```

What Konsole terminal printed:

```
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python3.8
/usr/bin/python3.9
/usr/bin/python3.8-config
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python3.6
/usr/bin/python3.6m
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3-config
```

I also tried to run *Xterm* outside of Atom (It was already installed on my OS), ran the same `find /usr/bin -name "python*"` command and got the same output as *Konsole* just showed (Yes, that means that executing `python3.9` command also worked fine).

Both *Atom-Xterm* and *Konsole* are running */bin/bash*, but even if i run */bin/sh* problem doesn't resolve. Also, *Atom-Xterm* cannot find some commands like *sudo* or *zypper*, and content of folders */bin* and */etc* is also different.

My operating system is *openSUSE Tumbleweed* with *Linux*.

I doesn't have an idea of how this even possible and will appreciate any help.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you need to launch Atom from your shell in order to have access to all environment variables

Comment: @idleberg Thanks, i tried your solution and some others and it didn't work. Looks like it's just a bug, so for now the easiest way to solve this is to use my normal terminal. Anyway, thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the package platformio-ide-termnial and this gives you access to a terminal in Atom.

Comment: Thanks, this package is mostly the same as atom-xterm and issue did not gone. I came out with decision that it could happen because of my operating system, it's a rolling release distribution, some things may not work on it. So the good thing is that with your help, after i tried using several terminal packages i probably figured out why this could happen and where to continue my research